# How can I use a collection list outside its parent in another collection in assemble?

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, assemble, yaml-front-matter, grunt-assemble

Trying to use a collection inside another directory is proving difficult.

Main collection dir:
/src/templates/roles/one.hbs
Etc etc

Then in my main pages dir:
/src/templates/pages/roles.hbs

I am trying to use a collection list inside the above template but it's not working. Here's what I have tried:

```
{{#each pages}} {{title}} {{/each}}
```

This works inside a roles page but not inside a page outside or inside my /templates/pages/ folder

Gruntfile.js

```
assemble: {
      options: {
        helpers: ['handlebars-helper-slugify', '<%= config.src %>/helpers/slugify.js'],
        data: '*.json',
        // Set the "default" assets dir at the task-level 
        imageAssets: '<%= config.base %>assets/img', 
        collections: [
          {
            name: 'navMain',
            sortby: 'number',
            sortorder: 'ascending' 
          },
          {
            name: 'newsMain',
            sortby: 'postedon',
            sortorder: 'descending' 
          },
          {
            name: 'navAbout',
            sortby: 'number',
            sortorder: 'ascending' 
          },
          {
            name: 'navReport',
            sortby: 'number',
            sortorder: 'ascending' 
          },
          {
            name: 'navCondition',
            sortby: 'number',
            sortorder: 'ascending' 
          },
          {
            name: 'footerNav',
            sortby: 'name',
            sortorder: 'ascending'
          },
          {
            name: 'mediaCenter',
            sortby: 'name',
            sortorder: 'ascending'
          }
        ]
      },
      pages: {
        options: {
          flatten: true,
          assets: '<%= config.dist %>/assets',
          layout: '<%= config.src %>/templates/layouts/default.hbs',
          data: '<%= config.src %>/data/*.{json,yml}',
          partials: '<%= config.src %>/templates/partials/*.hbs'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= config.dist %>/': ['<%= config.src %>/templates/pages/*.hbs']
        }
      },
      misc: {
        files: {
          '<%= config.dist %>/': ['<%= config.src %>/templates/misc/*.hbs']
        }
      }
    },
```

Has anyone got an idea why?

Comment: Do you have an example of your Gruntfile.js to see the assemble configuration?

Comment: I edited the answer dooweb :)